# logstash filebeat service account for centos 7

Tags: linux, bash, logstash, service-accounts, filebeat

I am trying to get filebeat (for logstash forwarding) on a CentOS 7 environment to run under my created user account: filebeat instead of root.  I tried editing the `/etc/rc.d/init.d/filebeat` file to the following but to no avail.  I might be doing something wrong but still a bit new to BASH scripting that I might be putting it in the wrong place?  I attempted to follow suggested implementation instructions located [here](https://github.com/elastic/filebeat/issues/148)

For brevity, I am only showing the first part of the mentioned file as the latter parts are unchanged:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# filebeat          filebeat shipper
#
# chkconfig: 2345 98 02
#

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          filebeat
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.
# Description:       filebeat is a shipper part of the Elastic Beats
#                                        family. Please see: https://www.elastic.co/products/beats
### END INIT INFO



PATH=/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin
export PATH

[ -f /etc/sysconfig/filebeat ] && . /etc/sysconfig/filebeat
pidfile=${PIDFILE-/var/run/filebeat.pid}
agent=${PB_AGENT-/usr/bin/filebeat}
args="-c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml"
test_args="-e -configtest"
wrapper="filebeat-god"
wrapperopts="-r / -n -p $pidfile"
RETVAL=0
service_user="filebeat"
# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

# Determine if we can use the -p option to daemon, killproc, and status.
# RHEL < 5 can't.
if status | grep -q -- '-p' 2>/dev/null; then
    daemonopts="--user $service_user --group $service_group --pidfile $pidfile"
    **chown -R $service_user /etc/filebeat || return 1
    chown $service_user $pidfile || return 1
    chmod g+w $pidfile || return 1**
    pidopts="-p $pidfile"
    touch
fi
```

Previously I created a user account filebeat using similar to the following:

```
useradd filebeat -u 5044 -c "Filebeat Service Account" -d /dev/null -s /sbin/nologin
```

However, when I try and take a look at the process after starting it still shows as being owned by root:

```
[root@testvm ~]# ps -aef | grep filebeat
root     26030     1  0 13:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/filebeat -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
```

Comment: I'm not sure but from what I see in the doc here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-run-options.html - in Linux you will have at least one thread running as root for Go garbage collector. For other threads the privileges should be dropped. You can check all threads using `ps -eLf`

Comment: @alexK, I upvoted you for the documentation link, but upon testing the runoptions parameter it just didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

On RHEL/CentOS 7, systemd manages the service so the init.d files are not used. You should modify the unit file for Filebeat in order to run the service as a different user. The unit file is installed at `/lib/systemd/system/filebeat.service`.

You need to add a `User` option to the `Service` section.

```
[Service]
User=<username>
```

The user must have read permissions on the log files and must have search permissions (the execute bit) on the directory containing the log files. Filebeat uses `stat` to collect the inode of the file and `stat` requires the execute permissions on the directory according to its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).

Comment: This is partially the correct response so I upvoted you but not quite there yet...filebeat is running but not actively digging into the log files as specified by the prospector settings.  Could you provide guidance on the correct permissions I need to add to the new user that was created?

Comment: I updated the answer with a note about the required permissions.

Comment: Close, I sort of figured that part out myself.  But also need to add permissions for the registry directory, filebeat-log directory (if indicated) and possibly the config directory of filebeat?  Almost there...